RHEL 7.9 chown not setting owner correctly
I have a RHEL 7.9 server. I am trying to create a local account called sysadmin. I ran

useradd sysadmin
usermod -aG wheel sysadmin
passwd sysadmin

When I look in /home I see the sysadmin folder, but it has a different owner. The owner is a service account that is unrelated. If I run chown sysadmin:sysadmin, it does not change the owner, it stays the same service account. I don't see any related logs in secure or messages. There is no /var/log/auth.log or syslog files. Has anyone seen this behavior?

check /etc/passwd for duplicate numerical ids

(And if your system is configured to use account sources other than /etc/passwd, check those, too.)

@Gerald Schneider The problem was a duplicate UID. Creating a local user did not pick a new UID.
